"Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/[...]/jakartaee_10.xsd)" when creating Dynamic Web Project with web.xml in Eclipse
I created a "Dynamic Web Project" in Eclipse which generated this web.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" version="6.0">
  <display-name>userManagement</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

However, Eclipse promptly shows this error on the very file it generated:

Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/C:/Users/AKILAN B/eclipse/jee-2023-06/eclipse/../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas_1.2.500.v202302261818.jar!
/dtdsAndSchemas/jakartaee_10.xsd). For more
information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

At minimum, you want to check if this still happens on the current release, which is not what you're using.
